# Change beheviour of target function but not completely

Tags: c++, assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

**EDIT:** I know it's possible with OllyDBG, I made it working but still I need runtime version(CPP) so I could perform jump there.

In [this](http://pastebin.com/Lx5mwb8e) function(pseudo-code) inside the switch I would like to modify the operations in the case 115 e.g. change CALL 100CE3E8 to CALL 100CF1E9

It looks like:

(case 115)

```
sub_100CE3E8(a1, v19);
break;

1024185D   8B45 E8          MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-18]
10241860   50               PUSH EAX
10241861   8B4D 08          MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
10241864   51               PUSH ECX
10241865   8B0D A0B12A10    MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[102AB1A0]
1024186B   E8 78CBE8FF      CALL somelib.100CE3E8
```

And I would like to replace in this case specified part of instructions, e.g. 1024186B

I'm using MS Windows Detours 1.5 for performing this kind of operations and it works well in most of cases.

```
    void hSwitchFunction(int a1)
    {                                 
       //So what should I put here to jump directly to 1024185D, 
       //and don't replace the function completely? 
       //I mean I want to modify just the part of this function.
    }

//somewhere in the code
DetourFunction((PBYTE)0x10241630, (PBYTE)hSwitchFunction);
//somewhere in the code
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you gave, the variable of the switch is from function that return the value you need. and as you can see in the code. that to that value they are adding an pointer, decreasing value witch moved to v14. and then using it in the switch.
Also note that they calling it from the function. 
in some cases it may be important. 
So all you have to do is to copy the same changes and use it in your switch.

Comment: I know that but I don't know how to put the pseudo-code to hSwitchFunction body. So I could modify parts of it.